# How do I schedule opening of a HTML in windows scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I got a HTML site, `example.html`. I would like to schedule its opening on hourly basis, so I wrote a .bat file, `execute.bat` that I would like to schedule to open in default browser

```
@echo Off
start C:\example.html
```

Executing (double click) `execute.bat` opens the website without issue. However, when I schedule it, it doesn´t execute: in task-manager I see that the browser is doing something but I cannot see its GUI with the website opening.

I´ve tried scheduling via the bat file (giving the `C:\execute.bat` directory in the start a programme field), I did try giving cmd as the programme to run with the optional arguments of `/c start "" "C:\execute.bat"` and I also tried to specify the browser´s executing .exe directory to run the html in the bat file. These tries do not work.

Are there any particularities to be aware of when scheduling a HTML file opening in windows scheduler?

I´m working on Windows Server 2012

Comment: If you **do not** tick *Run only when user is logged in* it runs on a desktop that you do not have access to, so invisible.

Comment: This does the trick! Thx post this as a valid answer I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not tick **Run only when user is logged** in it runs on a desktop that you do not have access to, so it is invisible.

Answer (score 1):

This will run a file name example.html every hour.
the file example.html is in the same directory **where .bat file is**

```
:loop
C:\example.html
timeout /t 3600 /nobreak
goto :loop
```

Comment: Hi, nice loop solution however the prerequisite of it to work is that the machine is constantly on. The computer gets switched off bcs of the windows updates and that is why loop would not be a complete solution for me. Any ideas?

Comment: so you should keep this file in the startup folder so that whenever the computer starts.
It automatically runs that file.

Location of startup folder
C:\Users\USER NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: to find startup folder
1. open Run
`2. shell:startup`